# Configuring Caliper to print metrics during a test round?

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, caliper, hyperledger-caliper

In `hyperledger fabric` benchmarking, `Caliper` prints report result after finishing test round.

How can I configure `Caliper` to print or emit metrics such as *TX delay*, *TX success rate*, and *resource statistics* (cpu, ram, ...) during a test round for example every 5 seconds (not once after round finish)?

I want to have a benchmark and record these metrics along with my own metrics from workload module, then building graphs and see how these metrics behave.

Comment: I would say it is not supported in the caliper for customization.

Comment: maybe monitors and observers can do what you want https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper/v0.4.2/caliper-monitors/